# Installing Entity Framework does not update web.config in ASP.NET MVC 5 Project

Tags: asp.net, asp.net-mvc, entity-framework, web-config

Here is the install log:

```
Attempting to gather dependency information for package 'EntityFramework.6.1.3' with respect to project 'UserPrivilege', targeting '.NETFramework,Version=v4.5.2'
Attempting to resolve dependencies for package 'EntityFramework.6.1.3' with DependencyBehavior 'Lowest'
Resolving actions to install package 'EntityFramework.6.1.3'
Resolved actions to install package 'EntityFramework.6.1.3'
Adding package 'EntityFramework.6.1.3' to folder 'D:\MyProjScan_test_proj\vs2015_projects\UserPrivileges\UserPrivilege\packages'
Added package 'EntityFramework.6.1.3' to folder 'D:\MyProjScan_test_proj\vs2015_projects\UserPrivileges\UserPrivilege\packages'
Added package 'EntityFramework.6.1.3' to 'packages.config'
Executing script file 'D:\MyProjScan_test_proj\vs2015_projects\UserPrivileges\UserPrivilege\packages\EntityFramework.6.1.3\tools\install.ps1'...
File D:\MyProjScan_test_proj\vs2015_projects\UserPrivileges\UserPrivilege\packages\EntityFramework.6.1.3\tools\install.ps
1 cannot be loaded because the execution of scripts is disabled on this system. Please see "get-help about_signing" for
 more details.
At line:1 char:44
+ $__pc_args=@(); $input|%{$__pc_args+=$_}; & <<<<  'D:\MyProjScan_test_proj\vs2015_projects\UserPrivileges\UserPrivilege
\packages\EntityFramework.6.1.3\tools\install.ps1' $__pc_args[0] $__pc_args[1] $__pc_args[2] $__pc_args[3]; Remove-Vari
able __pc_args -Scope 0
    + CategoryInfo          : NotSpecified: (:) [], PSSecurityException
    + FullyQualifiedErrorId : RuntimeException

Successfully installed 'EntityFramework 6.1.3' to UserPrivilege
========== Finished ==========
```

In the Web.config, there is no change to show the entity framework details.

**Web.config**

```
 <?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>
<!--
  For more information on how to configure your ASP.NET application, please visit
  http://go.microsoft.com/fwlink/?LinkId=301880
  -->
<configuration>
  <configSections>
        <!-- For more information on Entity Framework configuration, visit http://go.microsoft.com/fwlink/?LinkID=237468 -->
    </configSections>

  <appSettings>
    <add key="webpages:Version" value="3.0.0.0" />
    <add key="webpages:Enabled" value="false" />
    <add key="ClientValidationEnabled" value="true" />
    <add key="UnobtrusiveJavaScriptEnabled" value="true" />
  </appSettings>
  <system.web>
    <compilation debug="true" targetFramework="4.5.2" />
    <httpRuntime targetFramework="4.5.2" />
  </system.web>
  <runtime>
    <assemblyBinding xmlns="urn:schemas-microsoft-com:asm.v1">
      <dependentAssembly>
        <assemblyIdentity name="Newtonsoft.Json" culture="neutral" publicKeyToken="30ad4fe6b2a6aeed" />
        <bindingRedirect oldVersion="0.0.0.0-6.0.0.0" newVersion="6.0.0.0" />
      </dependentAssembly>
      <dependentAssembly>
        <assemblyIdentity name="System.Web.Optimization" publicKeyToken="31bf3856ad364e35" />
        <bindingRedirect oldVersion="1.0.0.0-1.1.0.0" newVersion="1.1.0.0" />
      </dependentAssembly>
      <dependentAssembly>
        <assemblyIdentity name="WebGrease" publicKeyToken="31bf3856ad364e35" />
        <bindingRedirect oldVersion="0.0.0.0-1.5.2.14234" newVersion="1.5.2.14234" />
      </dependentAssembly>
      <dependentAssembly>
        <assemblyIdentity name="System.Web.Helpers" publicKeyToken="31bf3856ad364e35" />
        <bindingRedirect oldVersion="1.0.0.0-3.0.0.0" newVersion="3.0.0.0" />
      </dependentAssembly>
      <dependentAssembly>
        <assemblyIdentity name="System.Web.WebPages" publicKeyToken="31bf3856ad364e35" />
        <bindingRedirect oldVersion="1.0.0.0-3.0.0.0" newVersion="3.0.0.0" />
      </dependentAssembly>
      <dependentAssembly>
        <assemblyIdentity name="System.Web.Mvc" publicKeyToken="31bf3856ad364e35" />
        <bindingRedirect oldVersion="1.0.0.0-5.2.3.0" newVersion="5.2.3.0" />
      </dependentAssembly>
    </assemblyBinding>
  </runtime>
  <system.codedom>
    <compilers>
      <compiler language="c#;cs;csharp" extension=".cs" type="Microsoft.CodeDom.Providers.DotNetCompilerPlatform.CSharpCodeProvider, Microsoft.CodeDom.Providers.DotNetCompilerPlatform, Version=1.0.0.0, Culture=neutral, PublicKeyToken=31bf3856ad364e35" warningLevel="4" compilerOptions="/langversion:6 /nowarn:1659;1699;1701" />
      <compiler language="vb;vbs;visualbasic;vbscript" extension=".vb" type="Microsoft.CodeDom.Providers.DotNetCompilerPlatform.VBCodeProvider, Microsoft.CodeDom.Providers.DotNetCompilerPlatform, Version=1.0.0.0, Culture=neutral, PublicKeyToken=31bf3856ad364e35" warningLevel="4" compilerOptions="/langversion:14 /nowarn:41008 /define:_MYTYPE=\&quot;Web\&quot; /optionInfer+" />
    </compilers>
  </system.codedom>
</configuration>
```

Any ideas on why this is happening? It didn't happen on the previous project I built, and in that one I saw the EF details appear in Web.config once I installed it in the project using package manager. In this project, I tried uninstalling and reinstalling the package, but got the same result. Unfortunately I did not save my successful install log so I don't know what was in it to compare to this log.

Thank you.

Comment: Look at the error log, it's telling you why: "1 cannot be loaded because the execution of scripts is disabled on this system. Please see "get-help about_signing" for more details."

Comment: @jmoerdyk You're right, that helped me resolve the issue and I have posted the command used. The only way I can explain this behavior is the new updates that were installed on my system today.

Answer (score 0):

The following command in the project manager console fixed the issue:

`Set-ExecutionPolicy RemoteSigned`